# Creating an alertdialog in Android app inside a navigation menu to logout

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, android-alertdialog

I'll try and explain this the best I can and I'm sure there will be a simple explanation to this.

I have a navigation menu with a logout option.  The menu items are all in a switch case except for the logout which I have separated and used an IF statement.  I got it to logout and go straight back to the login screen but I didn't think that was great for UX so I tried to add an alertdialog box to give the user the option to confirm whether or not they definitely want to logout or not.

I tried this (this is just the switch):

```
navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new HomeFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
                    item.setCheckable(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_create_case:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new CreateCaseFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Create a Case");
                    item.setCheckable(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_barcode_scanner:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new BarcodeScannerFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Barcode Scanner");
                    item.setCheckable(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_checklists:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new ChecklistsFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Checklists");
                    item.setCheckable(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_create_report:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new CreateReportFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Create Report");
                    item.setCheckable(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;


            }
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_logout) {

                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alert.setTitle("Logout");
                alert.setMessage("Are you sure you wish to logout?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                i2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(i2);
                            }
                        });
```

So with this, the logout button does nothing.  Doesn't crash or anything.  Just does nowt.

Any help greatly appreciated.  Especially if I've done something stupid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a show statement:

```
alert.show();
```

It's similar to a toast, you have to explicitly call show() to show the dialog

Comment: There you go.  I knew I'd missed something stupid.  Reassuring though that I got the rest right.  Thanks a lot.  Just having another pair of eyes helps a lot sometimes.

Comment: Haha yea, sometimes it's the little things that get you, i just faced an issue about 5 mins ago where i had fetched data from a shared preference but i had initialized the preference in the next line :'D caused a null pointer for no reason lol :) Anyway accept the answer if it solved your issue

Comment: Done.  I had to wait for the correct amount of time to have elapsed before it would let me.  That'll teach you for pointing out my issue so quickly